# Project input error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want to use the developed listView,

i downloaded the jar file of the swipeList project from here:

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/downloads

named: 
swipelistview-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

and i import this jar file into my project in eclipse

however when i create an xml , like the example in your website:

```
<com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
            xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/relative"
            swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/layoutUpdate"
            swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
            swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
            swipe:swipeMode="both"
            swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="false"
            swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false"
            swipe:swipeAnimationTime="2"
            swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="5"
            swipe:swipeOffsetRight="5"
            />
```

i get an error message in this line:

[image: error message]

can someone tell me where am i wrong please?

thanks alot